# In a cross-platform .NET Core executable, how can I specify paths to native dependencies / where do I put them?

Tags: .net-core, pinvoke

I've been using p/invoke to call some native dependencies in a cross-platform web app on .NET Core. This only works because I've specifically installed and `ldconfig`ed those dependencies.

Ideally I'd like to be able to run `dotnet publish --self-contained` against the appropriate platform and have that command include all the `so` files it needs, whereever they need to be, without `ldconfig`. I don't know if this is possible.

So my questions are:

1. Where does .NET core look for native dependencies if you do not use `ldconfig`? Does it matter if its a web app?
2. If the answer to (1) is not "nowhere," how can I include these dependencies when I do `dotnet publish`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The self-contained option is meant to create a portable publish option. The output folder would contain all required native and any set up required to run in the specified platform without the need of installations. All dll dependencies must be in the bin folder.